# Re-render popup automatically to show latest event information

Tags: react-big-calendar

I am using react-big-calendar to show events in only Month view. Now when the number of events grow in a single day and the '+{total} more' text starts to appear and when i click on it a popup appears with the current event information and when i change the event from the popup then that popup do not re-renders automatically to show the latest event information instead i have to do it manually verytime.

I am only using a Month view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jFAI.png

Now I want to see all the latest event information in the popup when i change the event information from the popup, I tried to do it forcefully by closing and opening the popup but it doesn't work:

```
<Calendar
          localizer={localizer}
          showAllEvents={false}
          defaultView={Views.MONTH}
          events={myEvents}
          style={calendarHeight}
          eventPropGetter={myStyle}
          onNavigate={handleCalendarNavigate}
          popup={true}
          views={['month']}/>
```

I tried opening and closing the popup forcefully but then also it was not working so i have to do it manually.